# Servlet mapping using annotation not working

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to do servlet mapping using annotation and it isn't working. In the past I've managed to get servlet mapping to work using some trial and error but I really don't want to do that, not anymore.

Here is the servlet placed.

```
|
|src
    |abc.cde.fgh
            |SearchDatabase.java
```

Here is the annotation I have added in SearchDatabase.java
`@WebServlet("/pages/SearchDatabase")`

I get the 404 (Not Found) when calling the servlet by GET on
`http://localhost:8080/MyProject/pages/SearchDatabase?term=1`

Here is the web.xml which I was not using initially because I didn't require that. I read that to use @WebServlet annotation, I need to have a web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>MyProject</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Please explain what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: How exactly is JS/jQuery relevant to this all? Are you implying that it all works fine when you enter servlet's URL straight in browser's address bar? If you actually also face a 404 there, then all that JS/jQuery only adds irrelevant noise to the question. You'd then better edit and eliminate noise. And, are you also really implying that it works fine when you map servlet in `web.xml` instead of by annotation? Nothing in the question indicates that you've actually tried the XML way.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but is this servlet actually compiled to a .class and deployed inside the war in the WEB-INF/classes/abc/cde/fgh folder?

Comment: You need to add the attribute metadata-complete="false"  to the root element web-app in your web.xml file.

Comment: Isn't `metadata-complete="false"` the default, when not specified?

Comment: Maybe it is the default. I guess you should do what BalusC suggested. Get rid of all the Javascript and jQuery stuff and get it down to bare bones.

Comment: @BalusC I have added jQuery and JS tags since that is what calls the servlet. I have never used the `web.xml` way of mapping servlets because from what I understand, annotation is the newer way. I added the web.xml file after seeing your link to the 'servlets' tag wiki page. 

From what I understand from webkit inspector I am calling `MyProject/pages/SearchDatabase` which I have correctly mapped in `@WebServlet`. I am not aware that I could directly enter the servlet URL in browser. Tried that `http://localhost:8080/eDW_Product_Dashboard/SearchDatabase`, not working. It is giving me 404.

Comment: @Gimby I have not exported it to a WAR file yet. Running it directly from eclipse.

Comment: Those URLs are different? Anyway, you have still not confirmed if mapping the servlet in `web.xml` works. Your question title implies that.

Comment: You can't run a webapp directly from Eclipse, it will be deployed to a server first. You just don't see it happening until you actually go look at the server.

Comment: @Gimby I have configured a tomcat server to run this from Eclipse. I just haven't created a WAR yet.

Comment: If you're going to be that resistant to actually being helped, I wish you good luck.

Comment: @Gimby I didn't mean to be resistive. It's just that this was how I was given training to use servlets, directly from eclipse. Anyway, I just deployed it as a WAR file in tomcat's webapp directory. I am not getting a 404 error anymore. The status is 200. But the weird part is, now I ran it directly from within eclipse without creating a WAR and it is working fine!!

This was my problem all along. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I didn't change any code between when I posted the question and now. I am guessing this has something to do with how I configure the server or something!

Comment: @BalusC It is working now without any change in code. Probably I would shutting down eclipse or server or something cause it to work. Can you point me towards the right way to configure server settings in eclipse if that is what you think the problem is?